# Get view which is created by onCreateOptionMenu(ActionMenu) - ToolBar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu

I'm trying to get `View` from Menu which is been generated with help of `onCreateOptionMenu()` and tied to right corner of `ToolBar`.

*Reason :*

I want to display `ShowCaseView` which  shows features of my application which is associated with Menu on ToolBar.

*Tried :*

1. Setting ActionView(actionViewClass). Then getting view with help of

   ```
   (View)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search); //which returns null every time.
   ```
2. Finding that view from Activity - it does return view but not in first attempt.

   ```
   getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).findViewById(R.id.action_award)
   ```
3. I do get ToolBar - Back Button(ImageButton) view with help of

   ```
    mToolBar.getChildAt(0);
   ```

Here's my menu_mother :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.mobcast.MotherActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true"
        tools:ignore="AlwaysShowAction"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_birthday"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_toolbar_birthday"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_birthday"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_award"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_toolbar_award"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_award"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_event"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_toolbar_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_event"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_toolbar_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_report"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_toolbar_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_report"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

[image: ToolBar - DrawerIcon]

[image: ToolBar - Event Button which is created using onCreateOptionMenu]

Comment: Within Menu Option selection means in onOptionsItemSelected()?

Comment: @Heyyou I'm using ShowCaseView library which requires view to show information about that view and what it does. That's why i need those view which i created from onCreateOptionMenu(). Any enlightenment on that?

Comment: @Heyyou I'm showing these showcaseview first time only. I don't want to trigger onOptionsItemSelected. Moreever onOptionsItemSelected also returns MenuItem. So no luck over there either :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. LayoutChangeListener**

As a workaround, you can add this in your `onCreate`, be reminded that the callback would be called twice, with the first time not able to find the view because the menu was not yet inflated. Therefore, I have included a checking of not null, which is needed.

```
final View.OnLayoutChangeListener onLayoutChangeListener = new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft,
                             int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
    mMenuSearchView = v.findViewById(R.id.menu_search);
    if (mMenuSearchView != null) {
      //do whatever you want with the view
      mToolbar.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
    }
  }
};
mToolbar.addOnLayoutChangeListener(onLayoutChangeListener);
```

**2. FindView with Help of DecorView**

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
         View mMenuAwardView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).findViewById(R.id.action_award)
 },2000);
```

Comment: I did call it on oncreateoptionmenu. But no luck in there either.

Comment: Lemme try these one! With the help of `getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).findViewById(R.id.action_award)` i do get view same was as per your answer i need it to call twice.

Comment: Yes, I have read that too. However, personally I am not so certain of the reason behind `getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).findViewById(R.id‌​.action_award)` but this `onLayoutChangeListener`